# Unable to Access Autodesk Construction Cloud's All hubs using GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, autodesk-forge

I have Autodesk Construction Cloud Subscribed account, But still I'm unable to get all hubs using graphQL Query. I am getting the fusion 360 hubs but not ACC hubs. Is there any other way to get all hubs from ACC account?

I have tried following query to get all the hubs of ACC.

```
query GetHubs {
  hubs {
    results {
      name
      id
    }
  }
}
```